# Como resolver problema do menu dropdown que não funciona no android?

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

Eu estou aprendendo a programar, ja fiz o site completo, e esta praticamente do jeito que eu queria, a principio tive problemas com IE o menu nao funcionava de jeito nenhum, reformulei o menu, utilizei exemplos que peguei na internet, entendi todo o codigo e finalmente consegui fazer funcionar corretamente, porém hj dia 30/01/2016 descobri que o menu dropdown nao funciona no android, ele não abre! Gostaria de ajuda com esse problema. O meu site ja esta funcionando www.institutoech.com.br se puderem testar em seus smartphones ja agradeço.

```js
/**
 * Created by marcos paulo on 22/01/2016.
 */


var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer  = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}


// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = mclose;
// -->
```

```css
/*------- menu pagina principal -----*/

#sddm
 {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 z-index: 30;}

#sddm li
{ margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 font: bold 11px arial}

#sddm li a
{ display: block;
 margin: 5px -9px 0 0;
 padding: 8px 0px;
 width: 117px;
 background: #03647b;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: blink;
 border: 3px outset #7f9db9}

#sddm li a:hover
{ background: #03647b}

#sddm div
{ position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #03647b;
 border: 1px outset #7f9db9}

 #sddm div a
 { position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #03647b;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: 11px arial;

 }

 #sddm div a:hover
 { background: #49A3FF;
  color: #FFF}
```

```html
<ul id="sddm">
        <li><a href="index.html" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">INICIAL</a>
            <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m2')" onmouseout="mclosetime()" class="seta-baixo">FOTOS</a>
            <div id="m2" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
                <a href="galeria_parapsic.html" target="_self">PARAPSICOLOGIA</a>
                <a href="galeria_ebf.html" target="_self">E. B. DE FERIAS</a>
                <a href="galeria_turma2013.html" target="_self">TURMA DE 2013</a>
                <a href="galeria_turma2015.html" target="_self">TURMAS DE 2015</a>
                <a href="galeria_formandos_2014.html" target="_self">FORMANDOS 2014</a>
                <a href="galeria_campanha.html" target="_self">CAMPANHA 2015</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m3')" onmouseout="mclosetime()" class="seta-baixo">BIBLIOTECA</a>
            <div id="m3" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
                <a href="biblioteca.html" target="_self">ACERVO DA BIBLIOTECA</a>
                <a href="apostilas.html" target="_self">DOWNLOAD APOSTILAS</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="informacao.html" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">INFORMAÇÕES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="sobre.html" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">SOBRE</a>

        </li>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contribuir.html" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">CONTRIBUIR</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contato.html" onmouseover="mopen('m5')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">CONTATO</a>
        <li><a href="http://216.172.172.225:2095/cpsess3606054867/3rdparty/roundcube/?_task=mail" target="_blank" onmouseover="mopen('m5')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">E-MAIL</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Diego Felipe, seu dropdown é ativado quando o usuário passa o mouse em cima do menu e no Android a navegação é diferente.

Tenta chamar a função javascript também com onclick

Ex:

```
<a href="contato.html" onmouseover="mopen('m5')"  onclick="mopen('m5')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">CONTATO</a>
```

Creio que assim o menu vai ativar quando o usuário de android clicar no item. Faz o teste e nos fale se funcionou.

Valeu